# Run program with arguments instead of filling the values

Tags: c, shell, arguments

I have a small console application, that asks for a values to count with (scanf function). But I wanna call this program with arguments -> so I haven't to fill it manually.

My program looks like this:

```
./a.out
Give me 3 values:
```

And I have to write "3 78 63".

But I want this (run the program with arguments): "./a.out -3 -78 -63"

Is there any simple way, how to do it?

Comment: Ever heard of `argc` and `argv`?

Comment: Arguments that start with '-' are usually called "options" or "flags".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the `argv` array passed to the program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        for (int i  = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            char *arg = argv[i];
            // do something
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // ask for arguments via stdin
    }
}
```